# grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated

Tags: grpc

In colab, While doing the last part of cognitiveai.org/2020/09/08/… that means from client part:

```
!python /content/ranking/tensorflow_ranking/extension/examples/tfrbert_client_predict_from_json.py \
    --vocab_file="/content/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12_TF2/vocab.txt" \
    --sequence_length=128 \
    --input_file=/content/ranking/TFRBertExample-train.json \
    --output_file=/content/myoutput/ranking/train.scoresOut.json \
    --do_lower_case
```

I encountered with this error:

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "input tensor alias not found in signature: input_ranking_data. Inputs expected to be in the set {inputs}."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1628345826.159512315","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:0.0.0.0:8500","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"input tensor alias not found in signature: input_ranking_data. Inputs expected to be in the set {inputs}.","grpc_status":3}"
>
```

what is the problem??

Comment: Have the same issue, trying to figure it out